# Postgres connection via ssh

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, ssh, sqlalchemy

I have remote server `s1` running docker container with postgre database on port 5442 like this:

```
c21b87e0cfd9 postgres:14-alpine "docker-entrypoint..."   3 months ago Up 3 months 127.0.0.1:5442->5432/tcp database
```

and am using

```
ssh -L 5442:localhost:5442 root@s1
```

when i use beekeeper, i can successfully connect
such as:
[image]

## however,

in my app/service that uses/wants to use this database,
which is located in docker container on its own :

```
fdc9b6de6d12   <image using python3.10>    "entrypoint.sh uwsgi"    10 minutes ago   Restarting (22) 3 seconds ago <app that wants to use database>
```

i use in class DBclient:

```py
class DbClient:
   def __init__(self,uri):
       print(uri)
       self.client = create_engine(uri)
       self.client.connect()
```

When i look at logs (why the service isn't working) i see this:

```
service_1          | postgresql://postgres:<password>@localhost:5442/jackie //not going to share password for private reasons
service_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
// lots of module errors

.
.
.
// and finnaly
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5442 failed: Connection refused
service_1          |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
service_1          | connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5442 failed: Cannot assign requested address
service_1          |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

**Why is this happening and how can i connect to this remote database?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssh command I am using to create a tunnel:

```bash
ssh -nNT -L localhost:5552:s1:5442  root@s1
```

Then the database is available on localhost:5552

Try this, because maybe it is just a command option on the complex shh command.

If your application is running inside another container, it all changes of course.

Comment: i Solved it by directly forwarding port to ip gateway of docker

Comment: But this will only work if you have 1 service behind that gateway. Correct?

Comment: nope, i have like 14 services, but every service behaves like single machine so i can just map it on gateway for docker and assign different ports -> example:
ssh -L 172.10.14.1:5432:localhost:54342 root@s1 #for one database by one service
and 
ssh -L 172.10.14.1:5435:localhost:5442 root@s1 #for other
all services can see the gateway ip so the port is the one thing that divides it